# OCaml Triple every number in a list of integers

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

So I need to write a function that will triple every number in a list of integers

Here is what I have so far:

```
let number =  [1; 2; 3; 4];;

let rec print_list_int myList = match myList with
| [] -> print_endline "This is the end of the int list!"
| head::body -> 
begin
print_int head * 3; 
print_endline "";
print_list_int body *3
end
;;

print_list_int number;;
```

It doesn't seem to do anything useful, any ideas where I went wrong? Need it outputting but it also doesn't do that. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression:

```
print_int head * 3
```

is interpreted like this:

```
(print_int head) * 3
```

Because function calls (application) have high precedence. You need to parenthesize like this:

```
print_int (head * 3)
```

The similar case below is a different problem: `(print_list_int body) * 3` doesn't make sense but `print_list_int (body * 3)` also doesn't make sense. You can't multiply a list by 3. However, you don't need to multiply at this call. The `print_list_int` function will (recursively) do the multiplying for you.

**Update**

If I make the changes I hinted at above, I see this in the OCaml toplevel:

```
val print_list_int : int list -> unit = <fun>
# print_list_int number;;
3
6
9
12
This is the end of the int list!
- : unit = ()
#
```

Comment: Ahhh right! I see where I went wrong now! I've tried inputting that into https://try.ocamlpro.com/ the way I wrote it with the line breaks acting as when I press enter. (with your edits) The result in the end is... : - unit = () ....Do you know it's not printing out the list with the tripled numbers?

Comment: let () = List.iter (printf "%d ") number ... any ideas why that may not be printing the list after each element being tripled?

Comment: It prints for me in the OCaml toplevel (when I fix it up). The result of your function is indeed () (unit).

Comment: Your function doesn't change the numbers (you can't change the numbers, lists are immutable). It just prints out numbers. I don't know about the online system you're using so I can't comment on why you wouldn't get output. I'll show you what it looks like for me (above).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the explanation and everything - great help towards my learning! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the most elegant way to achieve what you're trying to do is to use `List.iter`. It applies a given function (returning `unit`) to each element of a `List`.

```
let print_triples = List.iter (fun x ->
  print_endline (string_of_int (3*x))
);;

val print_triples : int list -> unit = <fun>
```

And here you go:

```
# print_triples [1;2;3;4;5];;

3
6
9
12
15
- : unit = ()
```